# Como validar una linea a partir de un banco de palabras

Tags: java, regex

estoy intentando hacer un programa que valide una frase usando un banco de palabras como referencia, la frase tiene comenzar nombrando a algún animal seguido de alguna palabra que lo describa por ejemplo "Iguana verde", algo así:

```
String[] animales = {"Gallina", "Vaca", "Gato", "Perro", "Raton", "Tiburon", "Paloma", "Hamster", "Toro", "Aguila", "Halcon", "Iguana", "Rata", "Elefante", "Jirafa", "Rinoceronte",
        "Tigre", "Jaguar", "Avestruz", "Hipopotamo", "Cocodrilo", "Puma", "Rana", "Gorila", "Lobo", "Zorro", "Hormiga", "Sapo"};

    String lineavalida = "Iguana verde";
    String lineainvalida = "Iguana";
    String lineainvalida2 = "verde";
```

Estuve probando con esto

```
boolean valido = false; 
    for (String reservada : reservadas) {
        if (tPrueba.matches(reservada + ".[a-zA-z]")) {
            valido = true;
            break;
        } else {
            valido = false;
        }
    }
    
    if(valido == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Linea valida");
    }else 
    {
        System.out.println("Linea invalida");
    }
```

Pero eso lo que hace es que duplica el nombre el nombre del animal por lo que siempre va a marcar que es una linea, agradecería si me pueden ayudar con esto

Comment: Con regexes podés validar contra un array de regexes compiladas del tipo `/^Vaca/` (para que empiece por vaca), o `/verde$/` (para que termine en verde), y contra algo como `/^[:alpha:]+ [:alpha:]+$/` para asegurarte que sean dos palabras. Esto es muy poco escalable. Yo tokenizaría, contaría los tokens, y los buscaría en dos tablas hash. Es muchísimo más rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes optar por usar [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) para evitar usar regex y hacerlo en pocas líneas de código, para ello usaremos:

- [String.startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))
- [Stream.anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))

Lo única que comparación que haremos es si hay algún animal que empiece como tu texto y que la longitud del texto con el que coincide es mayor a la del animal.

## Código

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] animals = {"Caballito de mar", "Gallina", "Vaca", "Gato", "Perro", "Raton", "Tiburon", "Paloma", "Hamster", "Toro", "Aguila", "Halcon", "Iguana", "Rata", "Elefante", "Jirafa", "Rinoceronte",
                "Tigre", "Jaguar", "Avestruz", "Hipopotamo", "Cocodrilo", "Puma", "Rana", "Gorila", "Lobo", "Zorro", "Hormiga", "Sapo"};

        String[] tests = {"Caballito de mar rojo", "Iguana verde", "Caballito de mar"};

        boolean coincidence;

        for (String test : tests) {
            coincidence = Arrays.stream(animals)
                    .anyMatch(animal ->
                            test.startsWith(animal)
                            && test.length() > animal.length()
                    );
            if (coincidence)
                System.out.println('"' + test + "\": is valid " + '\u2713');
            else
                System.out.println('"' + test + "\": is invalid " + '\u274C');
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"Caballito de mar rojo": is valid ✓
"Iguana verde": is valid ✓
"Caballito de mar": is invalid ❌
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla es construir una expresión regular de forma "dinámica". Lo primero será comprender que para construir la expresión regular haremos uso de la búsqueda mediante sub-patrones `()` acompañado de alternación de opciones `|`.

Para el caso anterior está la función `buildSubPattern()` que tras pasar un arreglo nos retornará la creación del sub-patron que tendrá una apariencia así:

```
(Gallina|Vaca|Gato|Perro|Raton|Tiburon|...)
```

Lo anterior aplica para animales y colores, ahora simplemente complementaremos la expresión regular con algunos símbolos de regex dentro de la función `isValid()`.

Estos símbolos corresponden a `\\s` que equivale a un espacio en blanco y los que definen el inicio `^` y termino `$` del string con la expresión regular.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String lineavalida = "Iguana verde";
        String lineainvalida = "Iguana";
        String lineainvalida2 = "verde";
        System.out.println("Linea Valida 1 => " + isValid(lineavalida));
        System.out.println("Linea invalida => " + isValid(lineainvalida));
        System.out.println("Linea invalida 2 =>" + isValid(lineainvalida2));
    }
    
    public static boolean isValid (String line){
        String[] animales = {"Gallina", "Vaca", "Gato", "Perro", "Raton", "Tiburon", "Paloma", "Hamster", "Toro", "Aguila", "Halcon", "Iguana", "Rata", "Elefante", "Jirafa", "Rinoceronte",
        "Tigre", "Jaguar", "Avestruz", "Hipopotamo", "Cocodrilo", "Puma", "Rana", "Gorila", "Lobo", "Zorro", "Hormiga", "Sapo"};
        String[] colors = {"verde", "rojo", "azul"};
        String expression = "^" + buildSubPattern(animales) + "\\s" + buildSubPattern(colors) + "$";
        return line.matches(expression);
    }
    
    public static String buildSubPattern(String[] elements){
        String joined = String.join("|", elements);
        return "(" + joined + ")";
    }
}
```

> Dado que no existe soporte (una especie de base de datos) con todos los animales existentes y colores, deberás completar los respectivos arreglos manualmente.